# Is GameObject.FindObjectOfType() less expensive in performance than GameObject.Find() in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm on my last finishing touches with my indie game using Unity and I've been thinking about improving my game's performance. I was wondering if GameObject.FindObjectOfType() is less expensive than GameObject.Find()? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really care about performance, try using none of them - or at least minimise it.

Using these Methods will loop through the list of GameObjects and return the object and because of the looping it is pretty heavy on the performance. So if you use them, never call them in the `Update()`-Method, call them in Start() or any method that doesn't get called often and store the value.

To be honest I don't know, which one is faster. If I had to guess, I would say it is `GameObject.Find()`, since it's only checking the name, whereas `FindObjectOfType()` checks the components.
But even if I would consider using `FindObjectOfType()`, because `Find()` uses a string and you might want to avoid that, because of typos (if you are not storing it inside a single class and just reference the variable)